# Calling a winform control method from a separate thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, controls, backgroundworker

I'm writing a plugin that interacts with a winform map control that can display shapefile layers.  I have a timer that will start a background worker to make changes to the displayed shapefile layer.  Once the shapefile gets updated I call a method that's part of the shapefile layer object to refresh the the layer displayed on the map.  When I call the method it initiates a bunch of other events and methods that's part of the map control.  I continually get a Cross-Thread error when the the refresh is called.  Any suggestions how I could accomplish this?  Should I be looking at using something else besides a backgroundworker?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-the-gui-from-another-thread-in-c

Comment: You have do do it by Invoking to the UI thread.